# Dynamically loaded js is undefined while unit testing (karma, jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Dynamically loaded js is undefined while unit testing (karma, jasmine)
I'm working on an angular js app and 
I've js libraries which are loaded dynamically(appended to head on some action). They are loaded this way because system.js cannot load them.
E.g dtjava.js which is used for launching signed jar through jnlp. Example for dynamically js loading.

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://java.com/js/dtjava.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

And then I use dtjava

```
dtjava.launch({url: 'someTool.jnlp', params:{param1: "852237"}}, {javafx: '8.0+'}, {};
```

This works perfectly, but I can't mock dtjava because it is undefined.
So, is it possible to mock dynamically loaded js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hadn't found a solution to mock dtjava you can wrap code to a new function and mocked the function which will solve the problem.